# 100% height not working due to DOCTYPE in HTML5 ASP.net

Tags: css, asp.net, html, height

I am trying to make a Asp.net website, The homepage design is a single page portfolio style; by having each  or "projects" as 100% height of the view port underneath each other allowing me to use anchor tags. My problem is that when I am using the  tag it messes up my css and does not work properly so how can I fix this?

I have tried the following:

```
/* in CSS*/
html, body{
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
```

And I have added the height 100% tag to each of the parent divs and or elements of the divs I want to be 100% but still no luck. I am out of options!
I can't post the full code because it is way to long and I am on a different computer to my one with code.

Comment: Quick and dirty: `height: 100vh`
But consider structuring your HTML to accommodate a better approach.

Comment: I have tried that but it does not work for the both divs??

Comment: `vh` is a percentage of your view height, I assume you don't want the divs to be 100% of your page height. Best luck is looking into responsive design tutorials.

Comment: I am using visual basic 12 and am a rookie to asp.net so I do not want to mess up anything. And I have seen loads of responsive design tutorials and they are not my priority. I want the each div to be the same height as my web browser's view as I can use anchor tags then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you're asking, but I'm not completely sure, nor am I sure where the `DOCTYPE`, anchors or ASP.NET come into play.

**[Here's a demo](http://codepen.io/Oka/pen/ZYxZma)** of a full page document, with a few full screen child divs.

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow: auto;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Please keep in mind that percentage heights can become a headache really fast, so you need to understand exactly what you are doing.

*Also note, this page is running [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) which fixes browser discrepancies.*

Comment: As I am using vb and asp.net it already has all of those Normalize and other files installed. But this still does not fix my problem for some reason? might it be that some other part in the css is stopping the height from working?? because when I try it from a normal html page it works??

Comment: Yeah, sounds like you might have some excess styles that are overriding your intended ones. Without access to your code I can't say much else.